# How to fix FilterPane in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions

I want to fix the **Filters Pane** in my SharePoint Library. Also when I open my Library, Filter Pane should be opened.

[image]

Maybe it is possible to make in Application Customizer. Could you tell me please? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Propool, does below answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: Hi @Propool, any updated on this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint default capabilities as there are no settings available to change the default behavior (expand/collapse) of Filters pane in list/library.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Can we expand the filter pane by default to a SharePoint library?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-we-expand-the-filter-pane-by-default-to-a/bf99f89c-f579-4997-9e37-671dc5a95d17)
2. [Can we expand the filter pane by default to a SharePoint document library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/can-we-expand-the-filter-pane-by-default-to-a-sharepoint/m-p/2181721)